# Getting number of rows/columns from MAT Image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I was doing some plotting stuff when I realised that there was something wrong with my codes. So to do a test, while debugging, I tried to change all the pixels in the image into white.

Please view the code below. It should work right? I wrote this code in the past with no problem too. But... If you see the image below, not all the image become white. Only till less than half which is the "number of columns" but it's not suppose to be the case. Any idea why?

```
{
        //uchar* z= image.data;
        for (int i=0; i < image.rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j < image.cols; j++)
            { 
                image.at<uchar>(i,j)= 255; //make all the pixels in the image white
            }
        }
        cv::imshow("After",image);
    }
```

RESULTS (see "after" window):
[image]

Comment: This is most likely because the elements of the `Mat` are larger than a `uchar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are working with color image which means that its size is 3*m*n bytes. You turned only first m*n pixels to white.

Comment: Didn't see that coming. Changed to grayscale and tested, turns out you were right. Thanks for pointing it out(:

Comment: You are welcome. at<> template is convenient and has reasonable performance but it is also a frequent source of bugs because wrong types can be provided without compiler notification...

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the advice.(: I am using it as this is the only way I learnt via online. I think I stick to it for now.

Answer (score 3):

You should do it in following way:

```
 Vec3b intensity;
 intensity.val[0] = 255;
 intensity.val[1] = 255;
 intensity.val[2] = 255;

        for (int i=0; i < image.rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j < image.cols; j++)
            { 
                image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)= intensity; //make all the pixels in the image white
            }
        }
        cv::imshow("After",image);
    }
```

Comment: Yup. I do know how to do this, just that I forgot that the number about the BGR(OPENCV) channels in colour images. Thanks though (: